# jQuery and jQuery-UI same name methods in conflict

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, methods, conflict

In my HTML page, I have some elements in a menu which needs to be shown or hided with jQuery 1.7.1. But in that page I import jQuery-UI-1.8.17, too. When I wrote the code to show and hide elements (in NetBeans), I selected jQuery JS source, for hide() and show().

The problem is, when I re-enter in the IDE, some of that elements seems to be using jQuery UI source instead, because it has same name methods!... Maybe for that reason, sometimes, that elements don't appear and disappear as expected... How can I avoid this conflict in the IDE and hand wrote code?

Note: I tried to add the $.noConflict() before the    $(document).ready(function(){...}     function, but another plugin crashed in layout (jquery.layout-1.3.0_RC-30.2.js) with that, so I deleted it again.